# Rails - has_one association to one of two possible models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A question about Rails association, where a `has_one` association is to one of two possible models. Like a polymorphic association, but the other way around.

So I have two different kinds of bank accounts, both belongs to `UserConfig`:

```
class SwedishBankAccount
  belongs_to :user_config
end

class ForeignBankAccount
  belongs_to :user_config
end
```

The question is how to manage this in my `UserConfig`. It should have a `has_one` association to either `SwedishBankAccount` OR `ForeignBankAccount`, but not to both.

Comment: why you have not used  `polymorphic` association here?

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of how I could do that? Maybe I'm just blind but I don't see how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ploymorphic relationship. Add `target_id` and `target_type` column in `UserConfig` model

```
class UserConfig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Then you just use for model `SwedishBankAccount` As

```
class SwedishBankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_config, :as => :target
end
```

And in  model `ForeignBankAccount` As

```
class ForeignBankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_config, :as => :target
end
```

Comment: It feels weird that the `UserConfig` `belongs_to` the bank account, but if i'm right, that only decides where the `foreign_key` is situated.

Comment: Actually your foreign key of account is stored in `UserConfig ` model with `type`

Comment: I was thinking about the association names more than the placement of the `foreign_key`. A `UserConfig` can exist without any type of bank account association, but it should not be possible for a `SwedishBankAccount` to exist without an associated `UserConfig`. The `UserConfig` owns the bank account, not the other way around. I think that becomes somewhat unclear if the `has_one` is moved to the bank account instead. But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: I have changed my mind about this. This approach is the best I have found. Although I still think it's weird that a config belongs to a bank account, it guarantees that there is only one bank account connected to the model. In my own answer below, the `UserConfig` can actually have two bank accounts at the same time (which should not be possible).

Answer (score 1):

You can create abstract class `BankAccount` for this models:

```
class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  belongs_to :user_config
end

class SwedishBankAccount < BankAccount
end

class ForeignBankAccount < BankAccount
end

class UserConfig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bank_account
end
```

Here will be no table for `BankAccount`, but you can put there common parts of your models.

Comment: Didn't know that you could have an association to an abstract class. I'll test it! :)

Comment: I prefer this solution. It's clear that the `UserConfig` is the owner of the `BankAccount`, and also, as you say, common parts can be put in the abstract class.

Comment: I have encountered some problems with your approach. If I try to access the users bank account with `user_config.bank_account`, I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table ''`. The abstract class is obviously missing a table name. Any thought on how I can solve this?

Comment: @ehannes you right, I couldn't any find solution about that. Probably you should use Vishal JAIN answer, or ask another question.

Comment: I ended up with several issues using this technique. Methods like `build_association(attributes = {})`, `create_association(attributes = {})` and `create_association!(attributes = {})` will not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Having an association to an abstract class, as zishe was suggesting, was unfortunately no good idea (see comments on that answer). Vishal JAIN's answer will work, but I think it will make it harder to get a correct picture of the architecture because of the change of ownership.

I ended up having associations to both types of bank accounts. An ugly solution, but it was the best I could come up with. If anyone else have a better idea, please share your thoughts! :)

```
class UserConfig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :swedish_bank_account
  has_one :foreign_bank_account

  enum bank_account_type [:swedish_bank_account, foreign_bank_account]

  # Returns bank account of type determined by bank_account_type.
  # Returns nil if no account is associated.
  def bank_account
    return swedish_bank_account if swedish_bank_account?
    return foreign_bank_account if foreign_bank_account?
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach is error prone. A `UserConfig` can actually have two bank accounts at the same time. If someone calls for the `swedish_bank_account` or the `foreign_bank_account` directly, without using the `bank_account` method, it is a 50% chance that the returned bank account is nil or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new model called account with user_id being a primary key "no duplicates" and an account_id that points to his record in either ForeignBankAccount or SweditshBankAccount.

This way you will make sure no users will have more than 1 account at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, a `User` has one `UserConfig` and a `Profile`. The `UserConfig` should then have an association to the bank account. To introduce a new `Account` class is not suitable.